# Issue on building a project in QT using a CMakeLists configuration

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, point-cloud-library

I'm starting to use PCL (Point Cloud Library) programming in QTCreator environment. 
I load a PCL sample project in the PCL SDK, using its CMakelists file but QT doesn't build it. I do File -> Open File/Project -> open CMakeLists.txt and when I get to the window Run CMake it says:

> The directory "MyPCLDirectory/pcl_visualizer-build" does not contain a cbp file. QtCreator needs to create this file by running CMake. Some projects require command line arguments to initial CMake call.

I use MinGW Generator 32 bit. If I try to push "run CMake" QT doesn't do anything.

I'm on Windows 7, using PCL 1.6 all-in-one installer and QT 5.3.0

Comment: if you run `cmake' in console what's the output ?

Comment: I'm not using CMake GUI, I Try to open CMake configuration directly from QT. No output coming from "run CMake" button on QT...

Comment: I think you need cmake installed to process CMakeLists.txt. QtCreator just take the 'output' of cmake and display in its projects tree... Even the build step then is demanded to cmake generated makefile...

Comment: cmake it's not a gui program. it's a makefile generator

Comment: I have got CMake installed obviously. You can see the window I was talking about here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fp1ca6tnq3by875/QTCMake.png

Comment: Anyway, If I run "cmake" on command prompt it shows a compatibility list of IDE Generators of project files, QT is not among them, is it a problem (I can see all Visual Studio versions for example)?

Comment: I don't think... even on linux, cmake doesn't list qmake as generator, but several other kinds

Comment: OMG, I had to open QTCreator as Admin, otherwise it couldn't find the compilers.